# Bounties new-nav doesn't remember sort order

Tags: feature-request, bounty, new-nav

When I visit the bounties page, I like to replicate the old functionality of the "Featured" tab which was to sort by ending date with the soonest to expire first. The bounties pill box automatically links me to "size".

Can this be changed to remember my sort selection so that I don't need to change this every time I wish to browse bounties?