# Bounty new-nav doesn't remember page size setting if I change sort order

Tags: feature-request, bounty, new-nav

I browse Stack Overflow with 50 questions per page. Occasionally, I wander through the bounties page to see if there is anything I can answer. On initial page load, I see 50 bounties listed. However, when I [change the sort order from the default](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327602/189134), the number of items per page drops to the default of 15 instead of my pre-selected 50.

Can changing sort order remember my selection for number of items I wish to see per page?

Comment: This is likely related to [another page size problem.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312885/new-nav-page-size-resets-when-changing-list-pages-or-tabs-on-a-new-or-refreshed) (Not a _duplicate_ as the issue/fix could very well be different, just _related._)

Comment: I already gave up and using default (15) items per page, then everything *works* *sarcasm...